# JQuery wrap divs with numbered classes

Tags: jquery, class, numbered

This is somewhat tricky, assuming this scenario:

```
<div class='top'>

    <div id='page1' class='in'>
    Mickey
    </div>

    <div id='page2' class='in'>
    Donald
    </div>

</div>
```

I want to wrap the divs with the section class, numbering it level1, level2 etc resulting in this:

```
<div class='top'>

    <section class='level0'>

        <div id='page1' class='in'>
        Mickey
        </div>

    </section>

    <section class='level1'>

        <div id='page2' class='in'>
        Donald
        </div>

    </section>

</div>
```

Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: why is the extra </div> is closed? Is by mistake or intentionally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass a function to [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/), and it will be called with the index of the current element. That way, you don't even have to use [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("div.top div.in").wrap(function(index) {
    return $("<section>").addClass("level" + index);
});
```

Comment: Adding some CSS to micha's example to show it a little easier: http://jsfiddle.net/Bk9xM/3/